# Reference alias in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

In psql, trying to reference alias in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(pk, 6, 2)::INT AS _year
FROM
    listing
WHERE
    _year > 90
```

it causes error:

```
ERROR:  column "_year" does not exist
LINE 1: ...STRING (pk, 6, 2)::INT AS _year FROM listing WHERE _year > 90...
                                                              ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "_year" does not exist
```

Is it possible to reference alias in `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The real question is: why are you storing a year hidden in a varchar column?

Comment: It is stored by others (and actually it's identification number as pk)

Comment: Putting multiple pieces of information into a single column is even worse. A PK should not contain things like that

Comment: Thank you for the tip (it's really useful to me, as I was asking myself same question), but I'm afraid I dont have the privileges to make any changes to db. Perhaps it wasnt meant for queries like this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not possible as in sql, the order of execution is first, the where clause and then the select. At the time where clause is getting executed, it does not know what you have defined as an alias and so you will get that error.

You need to rewrite your query like this..

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(pk, 6, 2)::INT AS _year
FROM
    listing
WHERE
SUBSTRING(pk, 6, 2)::INT > 90
```

Comment: Ah, it's in sql basics... Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try this way

```
select * from (SELECT
    SUBSTRING(pk, 6, 2)::INT AS _year
FROM
    listing) a where _year>90
```