# Can't filter by nodes in field with type jsonb

Tags: postgresql-9.5, column-alias

Table has two columns: **id** and **data**.

Column **data** has type **jsonb**

json :

```
  "weight": {
    "qty": 300,
    "unit": {
      "name": "gram",
      "title": {
        "en": "g"
      }
    }
```

I want to filter by json's nodes **weight** and **qty**.

Here query:

```
SELECT
(product.data #>'{weight,qty}') AS weight
FROM product 
WHERE weight = 300
order by id desc
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR:  column "weight" does not exist
LINE 4: WHERE weight = 123
              ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 70
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference alias in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650246/reference-alias-in-where-clause)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241352/using-an-alias-column-in-the-where-clause-in-postgresql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040631/postgresql-does-not-accept-column-alias-in-where-clause